# Wrong return value if multple returns in function?

Tags: javascript

See this:

```
var x = function() {
    if(true) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

if( x === false) {
      alert("OK");
} else {
      alert("Wrong");       
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxvFy/).

Why is it "Wrong"? Why does this function not return `false` as expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To call your function use

```
if( x() === false) {
```

You were testing if the variable `x` was holding `false`, instead of testing the returned value of the function contained in the `x` variable.